# Submitting IOS app Xcode 5.1

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

It's the first time that I'm going to upload an IOS app. I followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rRlOdp4uZoo

When I go to DISTRIBUTE in Organizer it says: **"No applications records were found. Applications must be ready for upload on iTunes Connect before they can be validated or submitted from within Xcode."**

But in ITunes Connect it says "Prepare for Upload".

What could i've done wrong?

P.D: When I "Archive" my app for the first time I didn't have any problems. But now I'm trying to repeat the process and I get this:

**"CSSMERR_TP_NOT_TRUSTED
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1"**

If it is to hard to determinate what I'm doing wrong, can you provide me with a nice and easy toturial? (video-tutorial if possible)

Comment: If it says `"Prepare for Upload"` then it isn't ready on itunesconnect to upload you haven't filled everything in on there, itunesconnect needs to say`"Ready for upload"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]
Currently you are seeing same as this. Click on viewDetails button and in right corner you will see ready to upload binary button 
[image]

Click on ready to upload binary button and after finish this, try again to upload by xcode.
For more help vist here [How to Submit Your App to Apple](http://www.raywenderlich.com/8045/how-to-submit-your-app-to-apple-from-no-account-to-app-store-part-2)

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. But now I have a different one.... "Code signing operation failed.
Check that the identity you selected is valid." I verified my Bundle ID

Comment: It's problem for your provisioning profile . Please check all provisioning settings ..

Comment: I did the provisioning profile thing.. but I get the same error. I haven't found an updated tutorial to follow.

Comment: I resolve your this question problem, for ""Code signing operation failed" problem ask again question . and Do it complete by accepting answer with upvote. thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks for your help mate. I resoved the problem, and I'd love to give upvotes but I don't have enough reputation :( sorry

Comment: If you will accept my answer then you will also got 5+  reputation. Have you find arrow sign below of vote button